# WPF PasswordBox hint not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm trying to style the **PasswordBox** in **WPF** so that it can show **Hint**.
I'm doing this by using the following code in ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BudgetBuddy.Styles">
    
    <Style x:Key="PBHintStyle" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFABADB3"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                    <Border 
                            x:Name="border" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            CornerRadius="4"
                            Padding="5 2 0 0">
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="WARKTEXT" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Foreground="DimGray" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WARKTEXT" Value="Visible"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This code works but with a problem. It shows the hint, shows chars as password chars but the problem is after typing a password in the field it shows the hint over the password chars.

Here are some the screenshots:

[image]

Here is the Problem:

[image]

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Why the Visual Studio tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by handling the PasswordChanged event of the PasswordBox and set its Tag property to "True" or "False" depending on whether the Password property contains any characters and then check the value of the Tag property in the trigger

On xaml:

```
    <Style x:Key="PasswordStyle" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="False"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PasswordChanged" Handler="OnPasswordChanged"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                            <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="4" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="4" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="PassMessage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="   Password..." FontSize="34" Margin="5,0,5,0" Foreground="LightGray" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" BorderBrush="Transparent" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Tag" Value="False"/>
                                        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PassMessage" Value="Visible"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

<Grid>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" Style="{StaticResource PasswordStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="217,256,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450"/>
</Grid>
```

On xaml.cs

```
private void OnPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;
            passwordBox.Tag = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordBox.Password)).ToString();
        }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
        <Condition Property="Text" Value=""/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WARKTEXT" Value="Visible"/>
</MultiTrigger>
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
        <Condition Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WARKTEXT" Value="Visible"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

If the text is not empty or null, the hint will be shown, otherwise no.

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Property="Text"  is not recognized in PasswordBox.

Comment: Exactly, my mistake, you could try this solution to create the multitrigger :
[link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9010a8b9-eab3-4d49-a6ff-fbc9129c7946/wpf-passwordbox-condition-triggers?forum=wpf)